# CSS: background-size: 50% cover - possible?

Tags: html, css, background

Is something like this possible?

```
.background {
  background-size: 50% cover;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I hope you can better understand it now.
The image should remain proportional, even if a part should disappear.

```css
.background {
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/350x150'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: top right; 
  background-size: 50% 100%;
}

.text {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 48%;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='background'>
  <div class='text'>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div class='center'>
    <a href='#'>Lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cheers

Comment: you might look for :`background-size: auto 100%;` to keep the ratio of the image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No you can't**,

Here is the [formal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background#Formal_syntax) for `background-size`  property,

> `<bg-size>` = [ `<length-percentage>` | `auto` ]`{1,2}` | `cover` | `contain`

Which means whenever you have `cover` you can't have `length-percentage` (those `|` means OR)

---

instead you can use `background-size: 50% 100%` or `background-size: auto 100%`

---

**UPDATE** Based on your updated question you can achieve what you want using `flexbox`

```css
div {
  display: flex
}
div div:last-of-type {
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/") no-repeat center / cover;
}
div div {
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
    ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit
    augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation
    ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim
    qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My problem with 50% 100% ist that the pictures looks not very pretty on some display resolutions.

Comment: @xuniX I said in my answer that you could use `auto 100%`

Comment: The width should be fixed and the height should be dynamic.

Comment: `50%` is dynamic ;)

Comment: OK. I described it a little bit mistakenly. I have pics with different widths and the problem now is that when I make something like auto 100% the pictures are longer than 50%.

Comment: your issue is having `min-height` which stretches the img

Comment: Yes but it is necessary because on the other side is a text that needs the height.

Comment: again full snippet

Comment: @xuniX see updated answer (sorry for long delay in replying)

Comment: @dippas Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `background-size: 50% cover` itself, though you can make it so that the background occupies 50% of the width and 100% of the height. I believe what you're looking for is:

```
.background {
  background-size: 50% 100%;
}
```

I've created a fiddle demonstrating this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/73pbrstp/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not the same as cover unfortunately. It stretches the background in height.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this for your css background:

```
.background {
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/350x150') no-repeat right; 
  background-size: 50% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by creating an absolute inner div with the width of 50%. Inside a relative container that has a width of 100%. You can give the inner div a cover effect and align it to the right.